# I encounterd a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbformat'" when rendering .qmd file to html in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, quarto

I edited a .qmd file in VS code but failed to render it to html. The error information was as followed:

```
Starting python3 kernel...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Quarto\share\jupyter\jupyter.py", line 21, in <module> 
    from notebook import notebook_execute, RestartKernel
  File "D:\Program Files\Quarto\share\jupyter\notebook.py", line 16, in <module>
    import nbformat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nbformat'
```

I wonder how to resolve this problem.

I guess the problem was with the python interpreter but I don't know how to switch to another python interpreter under a .qmd file.

Also, I tried `conda install nbformat` in the command line and it was successfully installed. Next I rendered the .qmd file again the same error appeared again.

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to render the qmd file, and whether you can provide some qmd content to reproduce the problem in my vscode?

Comment: I am getting this exact same error. nbformat is correctly installed, but it is still happening.

Comment: P.S. I am not using Anaconda. I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find out which version of Python vscode is using. To to do this, run the following block

````
```{python}
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```
````

This will show the path to the Python version. Then in terminal you need to type

`PATH -m pip install nbformat nbclient`

NB I got this answer by going to the quarto vscode site, and looking at the issues. Simon Willison has published this proceudre here https://til.simonwillison.net/quarto/trying-out-quarto

Comment: just running `pip install nbformat nbclient` was enough for me